# Having issues sending multiple props in a single component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my app.js:

```
const App = () => {
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);
const [ filter, setFilter ] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Loader show={loading} />
      <Navbar active={filter} />
      <Main setLoading={setLoading} setFilter={setFilter} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my Navbar.js component:

```
const Navbar = ({active}) => {

    return (
        <div className={"filter-options" + (active ? " active" : "")}>
            <div className="filter-close">
                <i className="fa fa-close fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

export default Navbar;

This is my Main.js component:

```
const Main = ({ setLoading, setFilter}) => {
    const [ images, setImages ] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {

        const getFeed = async () => {
            
            setLoading(true);
            const response = await fetch(`https://localhost/api/feed`);
            const data = await response.json();

            const results = data.data.results;
            setImages(results);
            setLoading(false);
        }

        getFeed();

    }, []);

    const showFilters = () => {
       setFilter(prevValue => !prevValue);
    }

        return (
                <Grid container spacing={2} className="media">
                    {
                        images.map((image, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Grid container item xs={6} sm={3} md={2} onClick={showFilters}>
                                    <ImageItem key={ `image_${ index }` } details={ image } />
                                </Grid>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </Grid>
        );
}

export default Main;
```

The issue is that the `setFilter` being passed to the main component does not appear to be setting the correct value when a user clicks on the element. It should change between true/false with each click.

Any thoughts on what I may have missed?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I have updated the original post, that should have been a `useState`.

Comment: You don't seem to use `filter` anywhere, how do you know it's not getting updated?

Comment: @GG - sorry, I forgot to add that. My original post has been updated to show that it is used in my Navbar component.

Comment: @zeropsi Your code is working fine - https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-66925898-pfu70?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I clicked on the titles and is toggling the `filter` value, let me know if I missed something here